# Открытие новых изображений в слайд-шоу

Tags: python, алгоритм, изображения

Есть папка с картинками, новые картинки там появляются каждые 2 минуты, нужно сделать что то вроде слайд-шоу, то есть отображается картинка(1), через 2 минуты отображается картинка(2) и т.д
С помощью чего можно реализовать подобное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_files, delay):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.w = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.h = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.w, self.h))
        self.delay = delay
        self.pictures = []
        self.track_img_ndex = 0
        for img in image_files:
            self.pictures.append(img)            
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def show_slides(self):
        if self.track_img_ndex < len(self.pictures):
            x = self.pictures[self.track_img_ndex]
            self.track_img_ndex +=1
            original_image = Image.open(x)
            resized = original_image.resize((self.w, self.h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
            self.picture_display.config(image=new_img)
            self.picture_display.image = new_img
            self.title(os.path.basename(x))
            self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
        else:
            print("End of list!")

delay = 3500
image_files = ["/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object1.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object12ndImage.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object13rdImage.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object14thImage.gif"]

app = App(image_files, delay)
app.show_slides()
app.mainloop()
```

[Источник](https://issue.life/questions/51066746)